# How to change hour text to minute when using timer control

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `timer control` for showing Time left for exam. I am accessing time frome database (say 30min, 1hr, 2hrs). `30` is shown in one label and `min` in another label. For 30 mins I am able to display it as `30 min` and decrement it after 60 sec but how can I do it for 1 hr and 2 hrs? What value should I store in the database for 1hr and 2hrs, and how can I change hrs to mins when time decreases to minutes, and when `time left = 0`. How can I send it to finish button click, currently I am using code shown below

```
public partial class MarksExamStart : Form
{        
    int tik = 0;
    public MarksExamStart(string MarksSelected,string DurationID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = conf[2];//showing 30/1/2 in label1
        label2.Text = conf[3];//showing min/hr in label2                
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    } 
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == timer1)
        {
            tik++;
            if (tik == 60)
            {
                label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt16(label1.Text) - 1).ToString();//decrementing time here
                tik = 0;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `BackgroundWorker` if you update the GUI from a timer-tick event.

Comment: You should be storing the total time in a uniform format in the database, lets say all minutes. Then when you retrieve it, doing an integer division will show you the number of hours left, and a mod should give you the number of minutes left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the time to tick only once in a minute then you should set the interval to `60 * 1000`.

If you want to show time left for a test, you might don't want to use a simple integer but a `TimeSpan`. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan) you can read about it and see examples on how to show it.

```
public partial class MarksExamStart : Form
{        
    int tik = 0;
    TimeSpan examTime;

    public MarksExamStart(string MarksSelected,string DurationID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        examTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(conf[3]); // If that's not double you'll need to parse it and make sure it's in the right format
        label1.Text = conf[2];//showing 30/1/2 in label1
        label2.Text = conf[3];//showing min/hr in label2                
        timer1.Interval = 60 * 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    } 

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == timer1)
        {
            if(examTime.TotalMinutes > 1)
            {
               examTime = examTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
               label1.Text = examTime.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
               timer.Stop();
               // Show the time ends message
            }
        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: I think I will get annswer from it ,I will study it and come back

Comment: In start it is showing 30 Than after 1minute it is deacreasing and showing like this 00.29.00 ,after this it is not deacreasing ,how I should loop it so that it deacrements till it becomes 0,and how do I get in start it to appear like 00.30.00. And one more thing i have read at link you provided is The code that uses TimeSpan.FromMinutes is far slower than the Using the TimeSpan constructor with three parameters [new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)] was over two times faster.so is it ok if i still use fromMinutes

Comment: yes, i have a mistake in code @Durga . here, take a look now... i did not set the new value in examTime sry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35248/discussion-between-durga-and-no-idea-for-name)